# How to use python3 and still be able to use tensorflow?

Tags: python3

I installed tensorflow gpu with python 2. Now I installed python 3. But when I launched python 3 and import tensorflow it says tensorflow not found. How do I fix this ? How do I make python 3 have all the links from python 2 ?

Comment: Quite clear instructions for Python3 are at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: Setup a tensorflow virtualenv using python3